# How to bypass selectattr with "equalto" filter error when the there is no element verifying the condifiton?

Tags: jinja2

I am looping over a list of object and for each objects I would like to get the elements in the `array` field with `key` property equal to `1`, if any. I have tried `array | selectattr("key", "equalto", 1) | first` but it fails when there is no element satisfying the condition. I have tried using an `if` statement with `defined` condition, but it fails at the `first` and I can't avoid it since `selectattr` is a generator.

There is always the possibility to create my own `first` filter, but I am looking for a pure jinja2 solution.

```
{ 
  "objects": [
    {
      "array": [
        {
          "key": 1
          "value": 234
        },
        {
          "key": 2
          "value": 235
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "array": [
        {
          "key": 3
          "value": 256
        },
        {
          "key": 2
          "value": 231
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to manually convert result of `selectattr` to list with `list` filter?

Comment: Yes, and I found that the error I had was caused by something else... In the end `{% if o.array | selectattr("key", "equalto", 1) | first %}` works, same with `{% if o.array | selectattr("key", "equalto", 1) | list %}` and also  `{% if o.array | selectattr("key", "equalto", 1) | list | length > 0 %}`. Sorry for the misleading post, I should probably delete it.